# How to perform database operations using Async Task

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

My application is getting stuck while performing database operation after googling for solutions it was suggested that I use AsyncTask so that main thread doesn't get blocked.

I have created seperate class and extended SQLiteOpenHelper and implemented "OnCreate" and "OnUpgrade" method. But to implement AsyncTask I need to extend "AsyncTask". Now my issue here is that I have already extended one class and I can't extend another class for the same class.

My code is something like this.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.project.R;

public class Database  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    static final String dbname="Project";
    static final int dbversion=1;

    TableA r=new TableA();


    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Context Context;
    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context,  dbname, null, dbversion);
        try{
        db=getWritableDatabase();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        if (db.isOpen()){

            System.out.println("Database is opened");
        }
            else{


                System.out.println("Database is not opened");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

            Log.e(dbname, e.getMessage());

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
        db.beginTransaction();

        db.execSQL(r.r_Table);


        db.insert(r.Tablename, null, r.insertdata());
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        retrivedata();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            android.util.Log.e(r.Tablename, e.getMessage());

        }

        finally{

            db.endTransaction();
        }


    }//
```

Can anyone suggest how I can perform database operations with SQLiteOpenHelper within an AsyncTask.

Thanks
Siva

Comment: You could create a separate class for AsyncTask and call execute() method by instantiating an object for your AsyncTask wherever required. As far as i know AsyncTask is used for network operations. I don't think it is required for accessing SQlite DB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Santosh.. but my application is getting struck when I am retriving the data and logcat has "Main thread is doing more work... something  like this" hence I am forced to use Async class... You mean create a Async class saperately and call it in Oncreate of database class?

Comment: No, OnCreate of SQLiteOpenHelper gets called only once when u install the application. I suppose you want to use the AsyncTask to retrieve data. Just create a separate AsyncTask class in your activity or fragment and call functions in your class extending SQLiteOpenHelper to get the result. Hope this was clear.

Comment: This means even if I call my saperate Async task class in my database class, Main therad won't come into picture and saperate thread will be used to perform the required operation... Is my understanding correct?

Comment: if you call AsyncTask from database class, the code written inside doInBackground will run in separate thread. onPostExecute and onPreexecute code will run in UI thread. And calling is AsyncTask from your Database Class doesn't make sense to me. And that warning u mentioned appears in and after Android  version 4. That is not a big deal. you could ignore that. if u need a general structure then let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Santosh.. It clarified me many concepts please help me to clarify this aswell. I am calling Async class in database class because I want to carry all database operation from only one class so that code is easy to use and debug, Also if possible please give me the general structure... Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29184/discussion-between-siva-and-santhosh)

Answer (score 14):

In your `Actvity` add the following code, do the required changes,

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> {
    DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(
            getApplicationContext());

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
        dbConnector.open();
        if (dbConnector.getAllValues() != null) {
            return dbConnector.getAllValues();
        } else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        if (result != null) {
            conAdapter.changeCursor(result); // set the adapter's Cursor
            dbConnector.close();
        }
    }
}
```

execute this by `new GetContacts().execute((Object[]) null);`

Comment: Thanks Atif.. but this getContacts should get called somewhere in the code. My query here is when this method is called saperate thread will be used to execute or main thread will perform the database operations.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is always performed in the background not in the main thread, so the database operation will be perform in seperate thread. Sorry if I didnt get your question.

Comment: I mean to say If I call my Async task in a class that is run my main thread then what will happen? Operations under Async task are performed by saperate thread or main thread

Comment: @Atif Farrukh What does "...execute((Object[]) null);" do?  Versus "...execute();"  Does it mean execute the AsyncTask if the Object is not null otherwise just return?

Comment: @AJW you can use `execute()` instead of `execute((Object)null)`. It's an old answer, I dont really remember why I did this, probably I had picked it up from my one of projects where I MAY have passed an argument but changed it here for the sake of answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't extend a class from multiple classes as it violates the property of java because java doesn't support multiple inheritence so for your case you have to create a new class which will extend ASyncTask and override the abstract methods to perform all the database related operations.
Thank you