# Provide AsyncTask with arguments unknown to the UI?

Tags: android

I am trying to use **AsyncTask** on Android.

Obviously, the **AsyncTask** will be invoked in UI class.

So naturally, the only arguments I can give it are those the UI knows. However, if I want to, for instance, get something out of a database in the AsyncTask, how can this be done? Naturally my UI does NOT know the database, so how can the Task know it?

Comment: Call database handler class and use something like **dbHandler.getSomeData()**

Comment: But how could I call the database handler from the AsyncTask? The Handler is not UI so it is unknown to the UI and hence, also to the AsyncTask

Comment: Pass a context to it :-)

Comment: If I HAD that context, easy. But the gui is not allowed to know that context, as gui is not allowed to know the database. Is not that usually so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293022/how-to-perform-database-operations-using-async-task

Comment: Read through the link, did not exactly help. Why did you delete the rest of your comment? Look, am I wrong and the gui should actually KNOW the database?

Comment: **"Naturally my UI does NOT know the database"** : What exactly do you mean by that? Also what is your "UI"? An `Activity`? A `Fragment`?

Comment: An Activity. Well, wenn I learnt programming I was taught that never ever does the GUI now the Model. As the DB clearly belongs to the model...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "model" - are you following the MVC design pattern?

Comment: `the only arguments I can give it are those the UI knows.`. Nonsense. You can give it any argument you want.

Comment: Are you starting the asynctask from a button click or a listitem click? Just do what you want with a database before starting or in the asynctask. Where in this scenario would there be something what you name "the gui knows the database" ?

Comment: @newnewbie : The problem with Android and the MVC design pattern is it all becomes slightly blurred. The UI in Android when you use an `Activity` is essentially both the View and the Controller. The user sees the UI but also interacts with its controls (Buttons etc). As a result the `Activity` needs to "know" how to interact with the Model . There's nothing wrong with an `Activity` directly handling DB access via a helper class or using an inner `AsyncTask` to do it. It's quite hard to separate Android code into the MVC pattern if you take it too literally.

Comment: Right that means I rebuild my plans tomorrow (it is night here). Could you write that down as an answer so I vote for it?