# AsyncTask in DBHelper select?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to make my Android app be more efficient and faster, so I wanted to make the db calls asynchronous (using asynctask), but I can't figure out how.
Below is my code snippet:

```js
public List<POI> todosPOIs() {
    List<POI> POIs = new ArrayList<POI>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + NOME_TABELA, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            POIs.add(new POI(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7),cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9),cursor.getString(10),cursor.getString(11)));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return POIs;
}
```

EDIT:

I've did what you said and it worked but the app keeps being slow.                 Ive enabled strictmode so i could see why is it slow and this is my logcat. Any thoughs??

```html
03-12 09:07:02.385  28028-28028/roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro D/StrictMode﹕ StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=29 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=23 violation=2
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1118)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.applyBlockGuardPolicy(SQLiteConnection.java:1038)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLong(SQLiteConnection.java:592)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setPageSize(SQLiteConnection.java:244)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:213)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:972)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.todosPOIs(DBHelper.java:135)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper$getData.doInBackground(DBHelper.java:128)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.getTodosPOIs(DBHelper.java:115)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.Lista.onCreate(Lista.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3953)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5434)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:834)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 09:07:02.385  28028-28028/roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro D/StrictMode﹕ StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=28 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=23 violation=2
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1118)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.applyBlockGuardPolicy(SQLiteConnection.java:1038)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLong(SQLiteConnection.java:592)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setForeignKeyModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:274)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:972)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.todosPOIs(DBHelper.java:135)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper$getData.doInBackground(DBHelper.java:128)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.getTodosPOIs(DBHelper.java:115)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.Lista.onCreate(Lista.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3953)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5434)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:834)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 09:07:02.386  28028-28028/roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro D/StrictMode﹕ StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=25 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=23 violation=2
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1118)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.applyBlockGuardPolicy(SQLiteConnection.java:1038)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:635)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:313)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:287)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:972)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.todosPOIs(DBHelper.java:135)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper$getData.doInBackground(DBHelper.java:128)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.getTodosPOIs(DBHelper.java:115)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.Lista.onCreate(Lista.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3953)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5434)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:834)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 09:07:02.386  28028-28028/roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro D/StrictMode﹕ StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=23 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=23 violation=2
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1118)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.applyBlockGuardPolicy(SQLiteConnection.java:1038)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:635)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:316)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:287)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:972)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.todosPOIs(DBHelper.java:135)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper$getData.doInBackground(DBHelper.java:128)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.getTodosPOIs(DBHelper.java:115)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.Lista.onCreate(Lista.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3953)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5434)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:834)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 09:07:02.387  28028-28028/roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro D/StrictMode﹕ StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=21 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=23 violation=2
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1118)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.applyBlockGuardPolicy(SQLiteConnection.java:1038)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:635)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setSyncMode(SQLiteConnection.java:294)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:288)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:972)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.todosPOIs(DBHelper.java:135)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper$getData.doInBackground(DBHelper.java:128)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.getTodosPOIs(DBHelper.java:115)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.Lista.onCreate(Lista.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3953)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5434)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:834)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 09:07:02.388  28028-28028/roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro D/StrictMode﹕ StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=19 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=23 violation=2
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1118)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.applyBlockGuardPolicy(SQLiteConnection.java:1038)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLong(SQLiteConnection.java:592)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalSizeLimit(SQLiteConnection.java:264)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:216)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:972)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.todosPOIs(DBHelper.java:135)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper$getData.doInBackground(DBHelper.java:128)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.getTodosPOIs(DBHelper.java:115)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.Lista.onCreate(Lista.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3953)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5434)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:834)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 09:07:02.388  28028-28028/roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro D/StrictMode﹕ StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=18 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=23 violation=2
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1118)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.applyBlockGuardPolicy(SQLiteConnection.java:1038)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLong(SQLiteConnection.java:592)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalSizeLimit(SQLiteConnection.java:266)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:216)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:972)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.todosPOIs(DBHelper.java:135)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper$getData.doInBackground(DBHelper.java:128)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.DBHelper.getTodosPOIs(DBHelper.java:115)
            at roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro.Lista.onCreate(Lista.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3953)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5434)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:834)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 09:07:02.389  28028-28028/roteiro.pap.pedro.roteiro D/StrictMode﹕ 

......
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16293261/1576416

Comment: Having parallel AsyncTasks with db-access is not good. From personal experience I'd recommend builing a service for db access and have db-access async but sequential and from one thread, only.

Comment: @Fildor can you explain that better? If possible with an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
 private class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<POI>>{
            @Override
            protected List<POI> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return todosPOIs();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<POI> result) {
                if(result.size > 0){
                    //Do with the result whatever you want
                }
            }
```

and execute this with `new getData().execute();` wherever you want to call this `async method`

Comment: @hkskrs It helped but didnt solved it, please take a look at the main post :)