# Android The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, database, multithreading, listview

I'm trying to make an application with drawer menu and one of the option is to open an Activity with Tabs. In every fragment im  trying to show listview which oparate on database. I've got problem with too much work on main thread. It is skipped 66 frames or more. I should make this operation in Async Task ? Please help find my a solution what should i do?

```
public class test1 extends Fragment{

private OpenHelper1 dbHelper;
private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
public ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trening_activity_main, container, false);

    dbHelper = new OpenHelper1(this.getActivity());

    dbHelper.open();

    //Clean all data
    dbHelper.deleteAllCountries();
    //Add some data
    dbHelper.insertSomeCountries();

    //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
    displayListView(rootView);



    return rootView;
}





private void displayListView(View root) {


    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllCountries();

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            OpenHelper1.KEY_NAME,
            OpenHelper1.KEY_KIND
    };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[]{
            R.id.name,
            R.id.kind,
    };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    //as well as the layout information
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(), R.layout.trening_activity1,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);

    listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
            String countryCode =
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra("cwiczenie ", countryCode);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    EditText myFilter = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
    myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });

    dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return dbHelper.fetchCountriesByName(constraint.toString());
        }
    });}

}
```

Comment: Yes, database operations should be AsyncTask(s). Here is a good starting point: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: This link will help you to use the database in asynctask. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293022/how-to-perform-database-operations-using-async-task][1]

Comment: Doing anything with data(base) in onCreateView() is a bad idea. Move it to onViewCreated()

Comment: thanks guys i will check everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make database operations in the Main thread (or UI thread). You have to do this in another thread using an AsyncTask. So you already have the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Loader`, a `CursorLoader` to be exact. This will fetch the data from the database in a background thread. A callback method `onLoadFinished` will provide the cursor which you can then use to create/update your `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Check out the [example on the Developer site](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)